# Convert NSObject to RLMObject to save that to realm database

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, realm

As I want to have a separate RLMObject from my main model 
I created two separated models:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Story: NSObject

@property(nonanatomic, strong) NSString *title;

@end
```

and another model for saving the Story Object to Realm Database:

```
#import "RLMObject.h"
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface StoryStorage : RLMObject

@property NSString *title;

@end
```

In MainController I fetch stories from the server and add them to array of Story objects.

Then I pass a story object to DetailController by indexPath.row and display its data there.
Also I have an option to add that object to Realm Database.

To do that I created a function:

```
-(void)addToDatabaseStory: (StoryStorage *)story {
        [self.realm beginWriteTransaction];
        [self.realm addObject:story];
        [self.realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

When compiler reaches

```
[self.realm addObject:story];
```

it throws an error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Story isInvalidated]:
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400028eb00'
```

Could you give me an advice how to add and delete an object from RealmDatabase?
When I had just a single object as RLMObject when I deleted that object from Realm it threw an error "The object is removed and invalidated".

What is the better approach to delete the object just from RealmDatabase but still keep it in the Model for displaying in UI?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your desire to separate out the storage mechanism from your model classes and UI, but you need to think of Realm as more than just the storage mechanism.  It truly is meant to be the model classes that interface directly to your UI.  For example, its notifications system is very appropriate to interact directly with a UITableViewController's insertion/deletion/change of rows.

So as you get deeper into Realm, you'll quickly come to regret trying to relegate it to just the storage side of your app.  Let it *be* used for the model classes of your app, or at least those that need persistence!  All that conversion you're trying to do will result in 1) fetching a lot of realm objects that don't need to be fetched (slowing down your app and/or wasting a lot of memory), and 2) you'll wind up not leveraging Realm's notifications system and 3) a LOT of extra code and complexity (and thus likely a lot of bugs too).

As for your specific problem, you didn't show how you're converting the Story to the StoryStorage, but however you did that must be wrong because when you call the realm's addObject, it should never be able to complain about the Story object.  It should know nothing about the Story object (per the error "Story isInvalidated]").  The Story object's title should have been mapped to StoryStorage object's title in a way that nothing about the Story is later invoked.

Anyhow, it's moot because I think you're heading down the wrong path in trying to keep a Realm object in sync with a non-Realm object.  (If you're going to do that for many of your models, you might as well switch to CoreData, because you'd be using very little of what Realm offers - and you'll eventually have to make up for it with a lot of custom code). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
Before using two separate models I used just Realm Model.
However I faced a problem while deleting an object from realm database.

How to delete an object from Realm but still be able to keep it and display in another table controller?

Comment: You can keep Realm List objects populated with Realm objects that you want to apply to different parts of your app.  Another idea is to move an object to an in-memory Realm, since it sounds like you don't want to persist that object anymore, but still display it.  Another idea is to add a field to the class to indicate it should only be used for this other UI purpose.  So basically I'd be surprised if you truly needed the object deleted if it appears in *any* UI.  If you're worried your app won't get a chance to delete it when app is killed, then do a cleanup task on next launch.